# how to create NSMutableArrays in runtime in iphone

Tags: iphone, for-loop, nsarray

In one of my applications I have to create the array's in run time whenever it's required. As below:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

means instead of creating a single array like array1 I want to create the arrays based on i value. Like whenever the condition is satisfied in for loop.

New arrays would be like array0,array1,array2,array3,array4....etc

If anyone know please let me know. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an array of arrays? Like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     [array addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}

//get array 0
NSMutableArray *array0 = [array objectAtIndex:0];

//get array 1
NSMutableArray *array1 = [array objectAtIndex:1];

//get array i

NSMutableArray *arrayI = [array objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: hi fbernardo thanks for your reply.this is useful upto some extend b ut my concern is i don't want to create these   NSMutableArray *array0 = [array objectAtIndex:0];                                                                                                                         statically. in what way i want to create the arrays are like                                                                            

//get array 1
NSMutableArray *array1 = [array objectAtIndex:1];

//get array i

NSMutableArray *arrayI = [array objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: So don't... I showed you how to ACCESS them, I'm not creating them manually. You can just replace 10 by 1000000, and it will create 1000000 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to access a bunch of different arrays based on a naming convention: array"i".  You can't really create dynamic variables like that, but you can create strings and store those arrays in a `NSMutableDictionary` for easy retrieval.

```
NSUInteger count = 10;
NSMutableDictionary *arrays = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    [arrays setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"array%i", i];
}
```

Now when you want to access a particular array you can use:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [arrays objectForKey:@"array1"];
```

Comment: hi fbernardo thanks for your reply.this is useful upto some extend but my concern is i don't want to create these arrays statically like in what way you mentioned.

Comment: In what way i want to create the arrays are like  this as mention below.

for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
NSString *str=[NSString stringwithformat:@"string%@",i];
                                                                          
}
like this if i print the result in console. i will get the output in the manner which i mention below.
string0,string1,string2,string3…..etc.

Comment: The way I mentioned creates the arrays dynamically.  Essentially creating as many as the number you assign to `count`.  In my example of accessing an array, I store the result in `array1` only as an example to demonstrate retrieval.  Both my answer and fbernardo's answer are perfectly reasonable.  It just depends on how you want to access the stored arrays and whether you require sequential iteration.